# Android. AsyncTask. Paralell using of two AsynkTask in main Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I try to start two `AsyncTask` in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` function

My task is to start them same time but I look that Authorization process start after Directory Scan process has completed. Why?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    task1 = new MyTask1();
    task1.execute(); // Asynch ???

    task2 = new MyTask2();
    task2.execute(); // Asynch ???

  class MyTask1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      try {
    // Disk scan process with using some functions from MainActivity
    DiskScanProcess();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {

      }
      return null;
    }
  }

  class MyTask2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      try {
    // Authorizatin process with using some functions from MainActivity
    AuthorizationProcess();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {

      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation for AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), in the section titled "Order of execution", explains that "Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution".  If you want multiple tasks to execute in parallel, invoke them with executeOnExecutor().

Comment: OK. Thank you. One more question. What is more right for real multithreading in android: work with AsynkTask or start to manage threads manualy by own code?

Comment: Your question does not have a simple answer.  It depends on the processing you need to do on the background threads and your skill level.  The Android SDK offers many alternatives to a plain Thread for performing background processing.  In addition to AsyncTask, there is Handler, AsyncQueryHandler, Loader, IntentService, DownloadManager, and others.  If your background processing is short and simple, there is nothing wrong with using a Thread.  You may find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_q12gb7OwsA) helpful.